# Why do we need to add a * before the name of a function for linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

Why is there a need for * (in front of insertAtfirst)? I know that we use it for creating pointers and for dereferencing but I am unable to comprehend its logic over here.

```
struct Node *insertAtFirst(struct Node *head, int data)
{ 
struct Node *ptr = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
ptr->next = head;
ptr->data = data;
return ptr;
};
```

Comment: Because the function returns a `struct Node` pointer, that is why

Comment: It's part of the return type.  It declares that `insertAtFirst` returns an object of type `struct Node *`, i.e. pointer to `struct Node`.

Comment: This looks like "C" not "C++". 
malloc should not be used in C++, and even new is deprecated.
For lists use std::list

Comment: You should answer this question by more closely reading the tutorial that presented the code, or asking the instructor who gave you this assignment. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service; while we don't formally have a limit on "basic" questions, it is expected that you understand the fundamentals of the language you are using.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag. This code does compile in C++ but there is no reason whatsoever to use it in C++. Only C requires to deal with raw memory like that.

Comment: @PepijnKramer `new` is not deprecated, just discouraged in favor of `std::make_unique()`/`std::make_shared()` instead

Comment: @MedhavKanda usually you do a typedef to avoid having to write `struct Node` everywhere: `typedef struct Node Node_t;` allows you to replace other occurances of `struct Node` with `Node_t`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right. (Sometimes I just get a bit annoyed with how people are taught C++. They still seem to be using books from 20 years ago)

Comment: I hate recommending `typedef` for hiding information. It's fine for hiding an opaque object in a public API. Don't do this for internal structures though.

Comment: The recommended way to allocate space for a struct pointer like that, is `struct Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);`

Comment: @Cheatah the question was about the meaning of the star. Maybe a bit early to introduce the automatic coercion of `void *`, the benefits of passing a variable to `sizeof`, the notion of opaque structures and public APIs and a bit of bickering over programming styles, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

Even though this particular bit of code will compile in C++, it is clearly only suited to C programming.

The star is part of the return type, not the function name.

- `struct Node *` reads as "pointer to a `Node`"
- `struct Node * f(...)` reads as "`f` is a function returning a pointer to a `Node`"

Maybe using `typedef` will make it clearer?

```
typedef struct Node * NodePtr; // NodePtr becomes an alias to "struct Node *"

struct Node {
    NodePtr next;
    int     data;
};

NodePtr insertAtFirst(NodePtr head, int data)
{
    NodePtr ptr = (NodePtr)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr->next = head;
    ptr->data = data;
    return ptr;
}
```

I can only advise you to get familiar with `typedef`, it's a great way to make C/C++ code more readable and safe, especially when dealing with these pesky arrays and pointers.

Most languages will (wisely) hide pointers from the programmer in properly managed references. C/C++ are archaic languages that allow the programmer to deal with raw memory, which is a bloody dangerous business, as you will soon find out.

Using such a code in C++ is technically possible, but that would be a terrible idea. C++ offers much safer ways of handling linked lists.
Alas, C does not. So, if you're actually learning C, as your example suggests, you'll have no choice but to learn to cope with pointers. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The * is part of the return type of the insertAtFirst  function.
It tells the compiler what it should expect as result of this function.
It is not related to the function name itself.
So the code is telling the compiler insertAtFirst will return pointer to Node (Node*).
Inside the function ptr is declared as Node*.
Finally the function return ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function returns a `struct Node` pointer (`struct Node*`).

The placement of the pointer symbol is sometimes confusing, so I recommend to put it directly after the type name. e.g. `char*`